# Why does ReadRequest use bufio.Reader?

Tags: go

The method `http.ReadRequest` takes a `bufio.Reader` instead of an `io.Reader`. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because it uses `textproto` for parsing that requires `bufio.Reader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will use buffered reader anyway. But it will not automatically wrap your `io.Reader` into buffer because of `bufio.Reader` nature - it can grab more data from underlying `io.Reader` that algorithm actually need. And, since underlying `io.Reader` cannot push back that exceed data, it will remain in that buffer. In case of autowrap that buffer would be lost after request was read and your `io.Reader` become corrupted. Thus, it ask you to explicitly wrap your reader to prevent data loss.